# Draw the curtains= Open/Close?

Tags: word-meaning, idiomatic-language

I looked up 'draw the curtains' and the answers confused me instead. Some dictionaries say it means to close the curtains and some say the exact opposite. Does it actually mean both?

And if I want to keep it simple, can I say "close/open the curtains"?

Which one would sound more natural to native speakers?

Comment: If they are open and you are asked to draw them, you close them. If they're closed you open them. If they're half open you may stand for ages, uncertain of what is required of you.

Answer (score 1):

To draw the curtains does mean to either open or close them, or put another way, to change them from their present state to the opposite.

It is natural to talk about opening or closing curtains.

> curtain   noun [ C ]
>
> a piece of material, especially cloth, that hangs across a window or
> opening to make a room or part of a room dark or private: Heavy
> curtains blocked out the sunlight.
>
> **to draw (= open or close) the curtains**

[Curtain (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/curtain)